# Does Solr for TYPO3 have a dynamic range facet?

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-9.x

the request by our customer is pretty simple - they want the ranges of, for example, a numeric range facet to be set to values based on the min and max value stored in the solr index. at the moment we just define a "hard"-range like 5-500 with gap 5. but they want if the document with the lowest value is 15 and the highest is 1600 to have a range for the search facet from 15-1600.

i cannot find a solution for that in the documentation so i guess its not possible out of the box? what would be the solution here? should we fetch those ranges on pageload and manipulate the ranges to work based on that values?

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the `Examples` folder inside TypoScript?
There is an example for NumericRange, I think that's what you're searching for:

https://github.com/TYPO3-Solr/ext-solr/tree/master/Configuration/TypoScript/Examples/Facets/NumericRange

Comment: did i miss something? how is the numericRange in that example Dynamic based on min max values from solr index?

Comment: our solution was to use a custom partial template with a viewhelper that fetches the values